# Displaying an r10g10b10a2 Image

Tags: image, rendering

I have an r10g10b10a2 image were each channel is represented as 10 bit. Assuming that the monitor is able to reproduce 10 bit and the graphics card is able to handle 10 bit surfaces is there an API I can use to create a window and view the image in a simple way.

I am aware OpenGL or DirectX may be an option but not completely sure how to go about this.

I also understand that the OS window system/rendering/compositing has to be in 10 bit mode but from my understanding this can be handled in Windows.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Thanks

Comment: The standard Windows display is always 8-bit. You can use ``DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2`` or ``DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16`` as a Direct3D exclusive full-screen mode to get >8-bit color channels.